# What is the fastest mean to transfer a record in DCOM

Tags: delphi, winapi, com

I want to transfer some records with the following structure between two Windows PC computer using COM/DCOM. I prefer to transfer an array, say 100 members of TARec, at a time, not each record individually. Currently I am doing this using IStrings. I am looking to improve it using the raw records, to save the time to encode/decode the strings at both ends. Please share your experience.

```
type
  TARec = record
    A : TDateTime;
    B : WORD;
    C : Boolean;
    D : Double;
  end;
```

All the record's field type are OLE compatible. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would be far better asked with winapi and c++ tags. That would give you a better chance to find com experts. Were I you I would translate the Delphi record to a C++ struct.

Comment: What about a `VarArray` of type `varByte`? You can set or extract data using `VarArrayLock` and `VarArrayUnlock`. Just use pointer math or a cast to a pointer of a type that represents an `array[0..somethingbig] of TARec` to pass or extract data.

Comment: Hi, thank you David for the suggestion, and Rudy I will implement what you have suggested and will reflect the result.

Comment: The COM way is a SAFEARRAY of records with user defined marshaler. You might get away with blitting as Rudy suggests but not if you have strings are any other non blittable types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Rudy suggests in the comments, if your data contains simple value types then a variant byte array can be a very efficient approach and quite simple to implement.

Since you have stated that your data already resides in an array, the basic approach would be:

1. Create a byte array of the required size to hold all your record data (use `VarArrayCreate` with type *varByte*)
2. Lock the array to obtain a pointer that is safe to use to reference the array contents in memory (`VarArrayLock` will lock and return a pointer to the array data)
3. Use `CopyMemory` to directly copy the data from your array of records to the byte array memory.
4. Unlock the variant array (`VarArrayUnlock`) and pass it through your COM/DCOM interface

On the other ('receiving') side you simply reverse the process:

1. Declare an array of records of the required size
2. Lock the variant byte array to obtain a pointer to the memory holding the bytes
3. Copy the byte array data into your record array
4. Unlock the byte array

This exact approach is something I have used very successfully in a very demanding COM/DCOM scenario (w.r.t efficiency/performance) in the past.

### Things to be careful of:

- If your data ever changes to include more complex types such as strings or dynamic arrays then additional work will be required to correctly transport these through a byte array.
- If your data structure ever changes then the code on *both* sides of the interface will need to be updated accordingly.  One way to protect against this is to incorporate some mechanism for the data to be identified as valid or not by the receiver.  This could include a "version number" for example and/or a value (in a 'header' as part of the byte array, in addition to the array data, or passed as a separate parameter entirely - precise details don't really matter).  If the receiver finds a version number or size that it is not expecting then it can report this gracefully rather than naively processing the data incorrectly and (most likely) crashing or throwing exceptions as a result.
- Alignment/packing issues.  Even with the same declaration for the record type, if code is compiled with different alignment settings then the size required for each record in memory could change (which is why a "version number" for the data structure format might not be reliable on its own).  One way to avoid this would be to declare the record as `packed`, though this comes at the cost of a slight reduction in efficiency (and still relies on both sides of the interface agreeing that the data structure is `packed`).

There are just things to bear in mind however, not prescriptive.  Just how complex/robust your implementation needs to be will be determined by your specific case.

Comment: This isn't a very COM answer. Blitting structs isn't the intention.

Comment: Hi David, please elaborate about your point. What is the ramification of using the way Rudy has suggested and Deltics tried to elaborate it. Do you mind to let me know more about SAFEARRAY and custom marshalling, may be some links referring to Delphi way to this will be useful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @David - Passing **raw** structs efficiently via COM is the *stated* intention (expressly desiring to avoid encoding/decoding at either end - i.e. marshalling).  There is no mention of requiring *COM Purity*, only (by necessity) COM *compatibility* and relative efficiency of the approach.  The "very COM" approach you mentioned (in comments) would be more complex to implement, trades encoding/decoding strings for "very COM" encoding/decoding (called marshalling), is *less* efficient than "blitting" thru a byte array and all to solve problems that the OP *does not have*.

Comment: @Zonouzi You can certainly do it by blitting the array as proposed here. So long as the type is blittable. I'm sure that you could avoid the memory copies also by using a reference to the array rather than a copy of it. And it will surely be more efficient to do it as Deltics describes. It's just not really the COM way. Whether that matters, I don't know. Probably not.

Comment: Ok so what I understood, please correct me if I am wrong, is that efficiently means no COM way, and COM way means complexity, hence slowness. So in my case, having pure OLE compatible variable types, what are the cons of using blitting compared to COM way. Is there any more things that should be concerned of? As I asked before some links to documentation on doing blitting and marshalling in Delphi will be helpful. Thanks in advance.